# The rigify is missinng the pole vectors for the elbows and knees

Tags: rigify

I'm using Blender 2.83 for a project I'm working on for a client. The problem is that the pitchiboy rigify which I'm using is missing the pole vectors for the elbows and knees. Is their a way to add those to the rigify or is there a switch to enable them? Any advice?

Here the video to demonstrate the missing pole vector"
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xoDgQ1wK-oQ

Comment: That is strange, they should be created by default. Have you enabled "Autorun Python Scripts" under Preferences > Save and Load?

Answer (score 0):

In *Pose Mode*, select the Right or Left IK foot control, open the <kbd>N</kbd> menu and choose the Item tab.

Under *Rig Main Properties* there is a *pole_vector* button that is set to 0, set it to 1 and your pole vector will appear. Repeat for the other foot.
[image]